# Application showing 2 different brands

Tags: branding

I have been checking other people who have tried to solve the same problem but couldn't find anyone in a similar situation really:

Our company has a number of applications and we share a common branding for all of them, displaying our company logo at the top-left as usual. The problem is that we are selling some of those applications to other companies and they want to show their logos as well.

I have been trying different options but I can't seem to find any that really works as in all of them the customer logo seems out of place.

Has anyone had to do something similar?

Many thanks.

Comment: Would the other companies be willing to create a custom avatar that could be used as the 'logo' within the UI? They could use the same avatar as they use on LinkedIn for example? Other than that, for me it's an exercise of colour/branding.

Comment: I think this is a marketing & communications discussion first and foremost, after which you work out how to convert the branding guidelines into the digital space.

Answer (score 1):

*Probably, the best possible approach is to show both logos, but at a distance from each other. E.g. at the top-left and the top-right corners.*

Let's have a look at how Google approached that problem in the G Suite version of Gmail:

[image]

The original Gmail logo is displayed at the top-left, while the company logo is shown at the top-right (blurred in the picture).

This way it's easy to understand that the application is Gmail, however, it is rather obvious that the solution is bespoke for the company which logo at the top-right.

The other possible solution is to emphasize the client brand like it's done in TeamViewer application:

[image]

We still can see the original logo of the application, but it's rather small and probably hidden depending on the operating system or the state of the application window (e.g. when it's maximized).

It wouldn't be a problem if we didn't show any logo at all, however, when we want to show the client's logo, then we need to show the original logo as well and it should be in the same (or similar) size.